# Problemas con los datos de mi api para poder graficarlos con ngx chart

Tags: angular, ionic, ngx

Estoy obteniendo datos de una api externa de la siguiente manera:

```
 this.servicioService.getData()
      .subscribe(resp => {
console.log(resp['data'])
   });
```

Los datos obtenidos son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria obtener los datos de esta manera:

```
datos [
{dateTime: '2021-08-26', value: '0'},{dateTime: '2021-08-26', value: '0'},{dateTime: '2021-08-26', value: '0'} ]

]
```

Para poder hacer un grafico con eso datos:

```
 <ngx-charts-bar-vertical [results]="datos" [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel">
    </ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

He probado de todo (añadirlo a una lista, objeto..) y ya no sé que más probar, alguien me puede orientar?

Comment: Agrega el json que devuelve la API.

Comment: Verifica donde recibes la información en el servicio, si la estás recibiendo como un array

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un array que se llame datos.
Luego recorres el array asi:

```
   this.servicioService.getData()
      .subscribe(resp => {
console.log(resp['data'])
this.resp['data'].foreach(value => {
this.datos.push(value);
});
   });
```